# problem with fetching results from mysql via php function

Tags: php, mysql

can some one point out the problem with this code? It supposed to fetch data from mysql but it returns blank. Here is the full code.

```
<ul class="list">

<?php

require("object/db.class.php");

error_reporting(0);

function entry_tickets() {

if($_SESSION['dojopress_global:root'] == false) {

$entry_ticket .= <<<ENTRY_TICKET
<li><p><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/32x32/apps/gnome-keyring-manager.png" />Access denied</p></li>
ENTRY_TICKET;

} elseif($_SESSION['dojopress_global:root'] == true) {

$q = "SELECT * FROM `notice` ORDER BY nid LIMIT 12 DESC";
$r = mysql_query($q);

if ( mysql_num_rows($r) == 0 ) {

$entry_ticket .= <<<ENTRY_TICKET
<li><p><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/32x32/status/dialog-information.png" /> Nothing to display</p></li>
ENTRY_TICKET;

} elseif ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
    while ( $a = mysql_fetch_array($r) ) {

        $nid = stripslashes($a['nid']);
        $note = stripslashes($a['note']);
        $type = stripslashes($a['type']);
        $private = stripslashes($a['private']);
        $date = stripslashes($a['date']);
        $author = stripslashes($a['author']);


    function note_type($type) {

       if($type == 1) { $type = "posted a comment!"; } elseif($type == 2) { $type = "raised a support ticket!"; } else { }
       return ($type);
    }

$entry_ticket .= <<<ENTRY_TICKET
<li><p><a href="viewer.php?nid=$nid" id="record-$nid"> $athor, note_type($type)</a></p></li>
ENTRY_TICKET;

    return $entry_ticket;

    }
}


}
}

echo entry_tickets();

?>

</ul>

<div style="clear:both;height:10px;"></div>
```

sorry forgot db.class.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect.php
$host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "au";

$connectClass = mysql_connect("$host", "$db_user", "$db_pass") or die ("Couldn't establish connection to database server.");
$dbObject = mysql_select_db("$db_name", $connectClass) or die ("Couldn't select database.");
?>
```

error reporting disabled error code

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\wamp\www\ageis\note.php on line 22
```

Comment: Returning a blank page could mean that PHP has been set to not display the error (kinda sensitive and useless for the enduser). Try setting it to display all errors.

Comment: Then change line 20 to:

    $r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_query());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mysql syntax looks bad. You have:

```
 SELECT * FROM `notice` ORDER BY nid LIMIT 12 DESC
```

try

```
 SELECT * FROM `notice` ORDER BY nid DESC LIMIT 12
```

Erik's comments should have pointed you in the right direction, however:

1. Figure out where PHP logs errors.  Either turn up php's error reporting level so you see more errors, or start tailing your apache error_log
2. You should always check for errors after running mysql_query and do some sort of logging on failure.  This is probably best accomplished by writing a wrapper function for mysql_query that does this, or using a 3rd party db wrapper that has already solved this problem.

Comment: And I should add, that: `or die(mysql_query())`   should not be in production code. Errors should be caught and logged so the end user won't see it, just like Frank says.

Answer (score 2):

You're redefining `function note_type` every time through your while loop. You have a `return` call outside the function, below it. Really I can't see how this is even syntactically correct. It looks like you have a large problem with mismatched brackets.

As for an actual database issue, you should check mysql_error() if no rows return from the call because it's likely something went wrong.

Also I recommend using `PDO` which is a true database class instead of the native function based ones.

Comment: Also if you have access to a command line you can do php -l your_filename.php and it will give you the errors. It's probably in your webserver log as well.

Comment: wow, you're right, the WTF-per-line count here is high.  `$athor` is spelled wrong in one place, and there's an attempt to call `note_type($type)` from inside of a docblock

Comment: FYI: Returning no rows is not an error, and mysql_error() will not tell you anything.

Comment: a yes manage to fail that part was in a bit of a rush I rewrote the entire code now. So it works the only part is note_type function which I can get to work...